# Count words in a column of strings in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe that contains queries and counts for a given time period and I'm hoping to turn this dataframe into a count of unique words. For example, if the dataframe contained the below:

```
query          count
foo bar        10
super          8 
foo            4
super foo bar  2
```

I'm looking to receive the below dataframe. e.g. the word 'foo' appears exactly 16 times within the table.

```
word    count
foo     16
bar     12
super   10
```

I'm working with the below function, but it hardly seems like the optimal way to do this and it ignores the total count for each row.

```
def _words(df):
  return Counter(re.findall(r'\w+', ' '.join(df['query'])))
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
df['query'].str.get_dummies(sep=' ').T.dot(df['count'])

bar      12
foo      16
super    10
dtype: int64
```

---

**Option 2**

```
df['query'].str.get_dummies(sep=' ').mul(df['count'], axis=0).sum()

bar      12
foo      16
super    10
dtype: int64
```

---

**Option 3**
`numpy.bincount` + `pd.factorize`
also highlighting the use of `cytoolz.mapcat`.  It returns an iterator where it maps a function and concatenates the results. That's cool!

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, cytoolz

q = df['query'].values
c = df['count'].values

f, u = pd.factorize(list(cytoolz.mapcat(str.split, q.tolist())))
l = np.core.defchararray.count(q.astype(str), ' ') + 1

pd.Series(np.bincount(f, c.repeat(l)).astype(int), u)

foo      16
bar      12
super    10
dtype: int64
```

---

**Option 4**
Absurd use of stuff... just use option 1.

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(
    query=' '.join(df['query']).split(),
    count=df['count'].repeat(df['query'].str.count(' ') + 1)
)).groupby('query')['count'].sum()

query
bar      12
foo      16
super    10
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another alternative with `melt` + `groupby` + `sum`:

```
df['query'].str.split(expand=True).assign(count=df['count'])\
                          .melt('count').groupby('value')['count'].sum()

value
bar      12
foo      16
super    10
Name: count, dtype: int64
```